# Error in subplot : TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'Timestamp' and 'float'

Tags: python

i have a data set and i have drawn a histogram of the data as :

[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gpu52.png)

i've calculated the mean a standard deviation of the data :

```
# Mean Calculations
mean1 = Read_FDX['%Returns'].mean()
mean2 = Read_PAG['%Returns'].mean()
mean3 = Read_R['%Returns'].mean()
mean4 = Read_UPS['%Returns'].mean()

# Standard Deviation Calculations
std1 = Read_FDX['%Returns'].std()
std2 = Read_PAG['%Returns'].std()
std3 = Read_R['%Returns'].std()
std4 = Read_UPS['%Returns'].std()

# Sort Data Based on Returns
df1 = Read_FDX.sort_values(by=['%Returns'])
df2 = Read_PAG.sort_values(by=['%Returns'])
df3 = Read_R.sort_values(by=['%Returns'])
df4 = Read_UPS.sort_values(by=['%Returns'])
```

so what i want to do is based on the data that i have in hand i want to plot the normal distrbution of the data set on it with the following:

```
fig , axes = plt.subplots(2, 2, figsize = (15,8))

axes[0, 0].hist(Read_FDX['%Returns'], bins=100, color='red')
axes[0, 1].hist(Read_PAG['%Returns'], bins=100, color='blue')
axes[1, 0].hist(Read_R['%Returns'], bins=100, color='green')
axes[1, 1].hist(Read_UPS['%Returns'], bins=100, color='black')
```

```
axes[0, 0].plot(df1, norm.pdf(df1, mean1, std1))
axes[0, 1].plot(df2, norm.pdf(df2, mean2, std2))
axes[1, 0].plot(df3, norm.pdf(df3, mean3, std3))
axes[1, 1].plot(df4, norm.pdf(df4, mean4, std4))
```

but i get this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/q0/mzp1n6xd4k72htbs4h2yyb0w0000gn/T/ipykernel_21585/1503543804.py in <module>
      6 axes[1, 1].hist(Read_UPS['%Returns'], bins=100, color='black')
      7 
----> 8 axes[0, 0].plot(df1, norm.pdf(df1, mean1, std1))
      9 axes[0, 1].plot(df2, norm.pdf(df2, mean2, std2))
     10 axes[1, 0].plot(df3, norm.pdf(df3, mean3, std3))

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scipy/stats/_distn_infrastructure.py in pdf(self, x, *args, **kwds)
   1868         args = tuple(map(asarray, args))
   1869         dtyp = np.find_common_type([x.dtype, np.float64], [])
-> 1870         x = np.asarray((x - loc)/scale, dtype=dtyp)
   1871         cond0 = self._argcheck(*args) & (scale > 0)
   1872         cond1 = self._support_mask(x, *args) & (scale > 0)

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'Timestamp' and 'float'
```

Comment: What's does the dataframe look like? SciPy is complaining that it's getting timestamps instead of numbers.

Comment: For debugging help, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (emphasis on *both* minimal *and* reproducible), including a data sample in text format that others can use to reproduce your issue. You can [edit] your question.